# webpack node esm generates require rather import

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, es6-modules, webpack-5

I am trying to create a webpack (version 5.72.0) bundle of a node server app which uses esm modules. The bundle is created successfully using this config file:

```
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

export default {
    entry: './build/graphql/server/web/WebServer.js',
    externalsPresets: { node: true },
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'Server.js',
        library: {
            type: "module",
        }
    },
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
    plugins: [
    ],
    target: 'es20201'
}
```

The problem is that I want to run it as an esm module where the type in package.json is set to "module".

The problem seems to be that the generated bundle is full of require statements such as:

```
module.exports = require("express");
```

This results in a run time error:

```
module.exports = require("express");
^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
```

How do you get webpack to generate import rather than require in the bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Set [`options.importType (='commonjs')`](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals#optionsimporttype-commonjs) to `'module'` for `webpack-node-externals`. Then you will get the **ESM** bundle JS file.

E.g.

Project structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── server.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

`server.js`:

```js
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server listens at port 3000'));
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';

export default {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './server.js',
    externals: [nodeExternals({ importType: 'module' })],
    externalsPresets: { node: true },
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        clean: true,
    },
};
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^5.80.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.18.2"
    }
}
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset main.js 361 bytes [emitted] [javascript module] [minimized] (name: main)
runtime modules 396 bytes 2 modules
orphan modules 42 bytes [orphan] 1 module
./server.js + 1 modules 222 bytes [not cacheable] [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 164 ms
```

Output

`dist/main.js`:

```js
import * as e from 'express';
var t = {
    d: (e, r) => {
        for (var o in r) t.o(r, o) && !t.o(e, o) && Object.defineProperty(e, o, { enumerable: !0, get: r[o] });
    },
    o: (e, t) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t),
};
const r = (0, ((o = { default: () => e.default }), (a = {}), t.d(a, o), a).default)();
var o, a;
r.get('/', (e, t) => {
    t.sendStatus(200);
}),
    r.listen(3e3, () => console.log('Server listens at port 3000'));
```

It uses ESM `import` for `express` package.

Run `dist/main.js`:

```
$ node dist/main.js 
Server listens at port 3000
```

If you remove the `importType` option for `webpack-node-externals`, you will get the commonjs module `main.js`.

Output

`dist/main.js`:

```js
(() => {
    'use strict';
    const e = require('express')();
    e.get('/', (e, s) => {
        s.sendStatus(200);
    }),
        e.listen(3e3, () => console.log('Server listens at port 3000'));
})();
```

It uses `require()` for `express`.

Run the commonjs `main.js`, it will throw the error same with yours:

```
$ node dist/main.js 
file:///home/lindu/workspace/webpack-samples/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/75758573/dist/main.js:3
        const e = require('express')();
                  ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/home/lindu/workspace/webpack-samples/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/75758573/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///home/lindu/workspace/webpack-samples/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/75758573/dist/main.js:3:12
    at file:///home/lindu/workspace/webpack-samples/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/75758573/dist/main.js:8:3
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:183:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (internal/modules/run_main.js:59:12)
```